# Memory leakage in C# while using very big strings

Tags: c#, string, memory-leaks

Inspecting memory leakage on one of my apps, I've found that the next code "behaves strange".

```
public String DoTest()
        {
            String fileContent = "";
            String fileName = "";
            String[] filesNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(logDir);
            List<String> contents = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < filesNames.Length; i++)
            {
                fileName = filesNames[i];
                if (fileName.ToLower().Contains("aud"))
                {
                    contents.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName));
                }
            }
            fileContent = String.Join("", contents);
            return fileContent;
        }
```

Before running this piece of code, the memory used by object was approximatly 1.4 Mb.  Once this method called, it used 70MB.  waiting some minutes, nothing changed (the original object was being released a long time ago).
calling to

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
```

decreased memory to 21MB (Yet, far much more than the 1.4MB at the beginning).

Tested with console app (infinity loop) and winform app.  Happens even on direct call (no need to create more objects).

Edit:  full code (console app) to show the problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace memory_tester
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Class to show loosing of memory
    /// </summary>
    class memory_leacker
    {
        // path to folder with 250 text files, total of 80MB of text
        const String logDir = @"d:\http_server_test\http_server_test\bin\Debug\logs\";

        /// <summary>
        /// Collecting all text from files in folder logDir and returns it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public String DoTest()
        {
            String fileContent = "";
            String fileName = "";
            String[] filesNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(logDir);
            List<String> contents = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < filesNames.Length; i++)
            {
                fileName = filesNames[i];
                if (fileName.ToLower().Contains("aud"))
                {
                    //using string builder directly into fileContent shows same results.
                    contents.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName));

                }
            }
            fileContent = String.Join("", contents);
            return fileContent;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// demo call to see that no memory leaks here
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public String DoTestDemo()
        {
            return "";
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get current proc's private memory
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static long GetUsedMemory()
        {
            String procName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
            long mem = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 ;
            return mem;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const long waitTime = 10;  //was 240
            memory_leacker mleaker = new memory_leacker();

            for (int i=0; i< waitTime; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Memory before {GetUsedMemory()} Please wait {i}\r");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.Write("\r\n");

            mleaker.DoTestDemo();
            for (int i = 0; i < waitTime; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Memory after demo call {GetUsedMemory()} Please wait {i}\r");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.Write("\r\n");

            mleaker.DoTest();
            for (int i = 0; i < waitTime; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Memory after real call {GetUsedMemory()} Please wait {i}\r");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.Write("\r\n");

            mleaker = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < waitTime; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Memory after release objectg {GetUsedMemory()} Please wait {i}\r");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.Write("\r\n");

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
            for (int i = 0; i < waitTime; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Memory after GC {GetUsedMemory()} Please wait {i}\r");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.Write("\r\n...pause...");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `fileContent.Length`? How many files are there in `logDir`? What size are they? Please provide a [mcve] (i.e. console app that calls `DoTest` and includes the `GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();` calls) so we can repro at our end.

Comment: Does it act differently if you run a Release build and `Start Without Debugging`?

Comment: How are you measuring the 1.4Mb / 70MB, and what makes you think there's a problem? Note: there *are* ways to read files more efficiently than `ReadAllText` if you're actually concatenating everything, but: I'm not convinced there's an actual problem here to worry about.

Comment: In logdir there are some hungreds files. very big (more then 100 MB).

Comment: Results are the same with and without debug.
I've measured it using another app, using the Process.GetProcessesByName and then .PrivateMemorySize64

Comment: I have tested this, with a boat load of files (4gigs), in .net 4.7.1 and after gc.collect im getting a difference but it is fairly small. 1 mb or so with GC.GetTotalMemory(false) are you sure something is not still in scope?

Comment: Any assumption that the GC aggressively returns address space back to the OS is invalid.  It does not spend a great deal of effort doing useless things.  An introductory book on OS design or tutorial is a good way to learn the distinction between virtual memory and ram.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you use stringbuilder on fileContent instead string, you can improve your performance and usage of memory.

```
public String DoTest()
        {
            var fileContent = new StringBuilder();
            String fileName = "";
            String[] filesNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(logDir);
            for (int i = 0; i < filesNames.Length; i++)
            {
                fileName = filesNames[i];
                if (fileName.ToLower().Contains("aud"))
                {
                    fileContent.Append(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName));
                }
            }

            return fileContent;
        }
```

Comment: I had tried it.  this will make the peak lower, Yet - same problem (memory is cunsumed and not released).

Answer (score -2):

I refactored version of your code below, here I have removed the need for the list of strings named 'contents' in your original question.

```
    public String DoTest()
    {
        string fileContent = "";

        IEnumerable<string> filesNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(logDir).Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains("aud"));

        foreach (var fileName in filesNames)
        {
            fileContent = string.Join("", System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName));
        }

        return fileContent;
    }
```